# Off-Canvas menu makes it so Footer isn't seen

Tags: html, css

so i'm confused as to why my footer section is hidden. I assume it is because the body is set to overflow: hidden, but it needs to be this way in order for the off-canvas menu to work. If I remove overflow: hidden on the body then the menu bar disappears when scrolling. I just don't understand why the footer section isn't showing since it is inside of the body element. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Here is a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b18wmdzg/

Html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="menu-wrap">
       <nav class="menu-top">
       </nav>
       <nav class="menu-side main-navigation" id="site-   navigation">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">page 2</a>
                <a href="#">page 3</a>
            </nav>
     </div>   
     <div class="menu-bar">
            <button class="menu-button" id="open-button">menu</button>
            <button class="nav-2">Contact</button>
            <button class="nav-2">Case Study</button>
     </div>
     <div id="content" class="site-content content-wrap">
         <div class="dummy-content">
             <p>hoaubobaowbeobafohweofhwohfowuheofhowehfowhohfohwfohohohohohohohohoh</p>
         </div>
     </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
        <p>dhooabobaweobofeobweh</p>
    </footer>

</div>
```

`

CSS

```
html, body {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #2a3032;
}

.container {
height: 100%;
}

.menu-wrap {
position: fixed;
font-weight: 700;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
transition: opacity 1s;
}

.main-navigation {
background: none !important;
width: 240px !important;
clear: both;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.menu-bar {
width: 100%;
height: 6rem;
}

.container > .content-wrap {
background: #f8f7ee;
}

.content-wrap {
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.container, .content-wrap {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.dummy-content {
height: 1000px;
}

footer.site-footer {
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
background: black;
}
```

Comment: Please include all of your relevant code in the post and not just enough to bypass the JSFiddle filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` means that anything beyond the bounds of the element is hidden; no scrolling. In this case, the `html` and `body` elements default to the dimensions of the window, and your footer is beyond those dimensions, so it is cut off.

My suggestion is that if you want your navigation bar to remain at the top of the screen, you give it a fixed position:

```css
html, body {
  background: #2a3032;
}

.menu-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #2a3032;
  z-index: 10;
}

.site-content {
  background: #f8f7ee;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 6rem; 
}

.dummy-content {
  height: 1000px;
}

footer.site-footer {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
 
         <div class="menu-bar">
                <button class="menu-button" id="open-button">Menu</button>
                <button class="nav-2">Contact</button>
                <button class="nav-2">Case Study</button>
         </div>
         <div id="content" class="site-content">
             <div class="dummy-content">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec congue magna. Sed ullamcorper velit id dolor congue convallis. In massa est, gravida a eros vitae, ornare aliquet nunc. Mauris elementum enim ut dapibus scelerisque. Etiam luctus orci id quam congue finibus. Proin consequat dapibus porttitor. Etiam pretium consectetur nibh non porttitor. Donec in leo sit amet neque cursus sagittis nec vel est. Morbi metus libero, suscipit in fringilla nec, molestie ut diam. Sed rutrum magna vitae orci pellentesque, non feugiat nibh sollicitudin.

 <p>Aliquam eget efficitur eros, eu egestas mauris. Morbi vel vehicula arcu. Integer viverra ipsum sed turpis laoreet dictum a vitae ex. Cras lectus libero, pellentesque quis nisi quis, tristique lobortis ante. Maecenas mattis ligula eget dui ultrices tristique. Sed in consectetur mauris. Fusce vulputate lacinia quam, sed ornare massa consequat in. Ut et turpis dui. Sed vitae diam vel sapien commodo mollis. Curabitur ante odio, tempor vel augue rhoncus, volutpat ultrices est. Curabitur nibh ipsum, dapibus et dignissim ut, faucibus eget nulla. Phasellus eget turpis rhoncus, pellentesque eros quis, iaculis quam. Nam laoreet felis sed nisi iaculis sagittis.

             </div>
         </div>
    
        <footer class="site-footer">
            <p>dhooabobaweobofeobweh</p>
        </footer>
    
    </div>
</body>
```

If you want to have another menu that opens on top of the first menu, then you can give it a larger z-index.

In general you want to avoid nested scroll bars; if something scrolls it should be the page as a whole, not individual elements.

Comment: This wasn't an exact fix, but you were right to remove the height and overflow on the html and body, then make the menu-bar position fixed. Thanks for your help Greg!

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is setting :

```
.content-wrap {
    height: 100%;}
```

whenever you set height to 100% you need to think on what that means.. in your case it meant 100% of windowHeight,  and since you had another div on top your footer this was pushed below the bottom ,

here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/b18wmdzg/1/)